# A Wonderfully Tricky way of Making any Positive Integer

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Make **all** positive integers, starting from $1$, using:

1. Exactly four $4$'s (and no other digit), concatenation being allowed,
2. Any standard mathematical symbol(s) and operation(s) not listed below.

But not using:

1. Addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, modulo reduction,
2. Logarithms, exponentiation, root extraction,
3. Floor, ceiling, fractional part,
4. Integral, differential, binomial coefficients,
5. English, Greek, or Hebrew or any other language letters (Note that trig ratios require the use of English letters, and hence are not allowed),
6. Any function or operation generated by you.

(And yes, it's possible.)

---

Enjoy! I'll be awaiting creative responses.

Comment: 一,二,三,四,五,六,...

Comment: $|\{4444\}|$, $|\{4444,\varnothing\}|$, $|\{4444,\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}|$, $|\{4444,\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}|$,...

Comment: @f'' chinese....well, I said letters and other digits are not allowed. The second solution is my solution too, with the $\varnothing$'s replaced by $\{\}$'s; would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: Letters and digits aren't allowed, but you never said anything about *characters*.

Comment: @f'' Hmm, looks like that was a bad puzzle to put up. Thanks anyway for your attention. :)

Comment: @Ankoganit Although i think that no puzzle is bad, but this one is a bit awkward to approach

Answer (score 6):

Easy :

> $ \mathbb{N}^* \cup [4,444] $

Comment: LOL what? N is a letter...

Comment: @Ankoganit That, my pal, is not just a simple N.

Comment: "Any [standard mathematical symbol(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Notation) and operation(s) not listed below." - is 5 meant to exclude $\Bbb{N}$?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution:

> The question asks for *any* positive integer, not *every* integer.  Hence 4444 will do.

Comment: And what about "starting from $1$"? +1 for the idea though. :)

Comment: Now I have replaced "any" with "all", sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Haha no inconvenience, just a bit of tongue-in-cheek. :-)

Answer (score 4):

There is a standard mathematical notation for all natural numbers using

> $0$ $4$s and no other digit, it's called [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding)

So all we need to do

> is to replace  $x$ with $44$ ($2$ $4$s concatenated)
>  in the standard lambda expansions of the Church numerals.

To yield

> $1=\lambda f.\lambda44.f44$
>  $2=\lambda f.\lambda44.f(f44)$
>  $3=\lambda f.\lambda44.f(f(f44))$
>  $\vdots$
>  $n=\lambda f.\lambda44.f(\cdots f(f(f44))\cdots)\space\space\space$  (using $n$ $f$s)

This way, we can also

> create zero
>  $0=\lambda f.\lambda44.44$

---

If we were only able to use $2a+1$ $4$s (some odd number of $4$s) we cannot do the above, but we can do

> $n=|\{444\cdots4, \{\}, \{\}, \cdots, \{\}\}|\space\space\space$ (using $2a+1$ $4$s and $n-1$ $\{\}$s)
>  As
>  $\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_m\}$ is a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics))
>  $\{\}$ is the [empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set), $\emptyset$
>  and $|X|$ is the [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of the set $X$

---

Going by the comment on Lord of dark's answer, I suppose $\lambda$s and $f$s are not allowed by not using #5 (any letters) - so the first solution is not a valid solution.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see

> ```
> !(44 ^ 44) = 1
>
>  4 >> ( !( (4 | 4) ^ 4) ) = 2
>
>  (!!4) | (4 >> ( !(4 ^ 4))) = 3
>
>  4 | 4 | 4 | 4 = 4
>
>  (4 | 4 | (!(4 ^ 4))) = 5
>
>  4 | (4 >> (!(4 ^ 4))) = 6
>
>  !!4 | (4 >> !!4) | 4 = 7
>
>  (4 & 4) << !(4 ^ 4) = 8
>
>  (4 << !(4 ^ 4)) | !!4 = 9
>
>  ((4 << !!4)) | (4 >> !!4) = 10
> ```

And in case you don't think I am making up the things

> [see this](http://ideone.com/8o4ItK).

Comment: I Like the answer, but have a question: are coding operators 'standard *mathematical* operators? I.e. Do mathematicians use them like this on paper and in books?

Comment: Logical operations is mathematics in IMHO. But I am not sure by the definition and scope of *standard mathematical operators*.

Comment: Logical operations, yes. Bitwise operations, I'm not so sure.

Comment: if they do, those are not the symbols they use.